# I want to move both .h and .c files from src to dst

Tags: command-line, mv

I managed to do so using `mv *.c *.h ~/` but I was wondering if I can compact it into a shorter command.

I tried the below which didn't work:

```
mv *.[c|h] ~/
```

Comment: Nice problem. As Yaron answered, it works without the |-symbol. In fact, that is the reason why it doesn't work: the pipe-symbol is interpreted by the shell. Escaping the pipe would work again, mv *.[c\|h] ~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the following format:

```
mv *.[ch] ~/
```

More info can be found in [glob wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

> **Globs**
>
> "Glob" is the common name for a set of Bash features that match or
>   expand specific types of patterns. Some synonyms for globbing
>   (depending on the context in which it appears) are pattern matching,
>   pattern expansion, filename expansion, and so on. A glob may look like
>   *.txt and, when used to match filenames, is sometimes called a "wildcard".
>
> `*.[ch] Matches any string ending with .c or .h`
>   `[abcd] Matches a or b or c or d`